# while loop output increasing digits and break

Tags: php

i have here a problem that needs to output the same pattern as below

how can i do this using while loop?
this is the pattern:

```
Write a program that will display the following pattern, given the value of n.
Example: if n=4, output
1
12
123
1234
```

or

```
   1
   10
   100
   1000
```

something like this

this is my current code:

```
int  i,x;
printf( "Enter a number:");
scanf("%d", &i);
x=1;
while (x <= i)
{

      printf("%d",x);
       x++;

}
```

sorry im beginner in programming

Comment: is this a php or a C++ question? Pick one

Comment: php question sorry

Comment: your answer is look like c question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int  i,x,y;
printf( "Enter a number:");
scanf("%d", &i);
x=1;
y=1;
while (y <= i)
{
  printf("\n %d",x);
  x=x*10;
  y++;
}
```

Comment: can i ask you more question?

Comment: Was the answer helpful..?? Yes you can

Comment: yes you answered my question. i have more question regarding do while loop. where can i send you the problem?

Comment: comment it here.. or you can create a new question

Comment: here:

if n=4, output
****
***
**
*

using do while loop

Comment: x=pow(10,i); while (y <= i)
{
  printf("\n %d",x);
  x=x/10;
  y++;
}

Comment: are you using while loop only?

Comment: x=pow(10,i);
do
{
  printf("\n %d",x);
  x=x/10;
  y++;
}while (y <= i);

Comment: is it okay to you if i ask your email?

Comment: i really need your help

Comment: please email me here adrianpascuaaaaa15@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()  
{  
 int  i,x,j;  
 printf("Enter a number:");  
 scanf("%d", &i);  
 x=1;  
  while (x <= i)  
   {  
    j=1;  
      while(j<=x)  
       {    
         printf("%d",j);  
         j++;  
        }  
      x++;  
      printf("\n");  
    }  
return 0;  
}
```